# How to center the nav

Tags: css, menu, alignment, html-lists, center

I found this really simple way to make responsive menu on w3schools ([article](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp)) but I have been struggling for a few days trying to center it horizontally.

html

```
 <ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
 /* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #111;}

/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}
```

Comment: [this](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav) is the code that I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle from you linked code: https://jsfiddle.net/gqm7zdf9/

A solid option is to add a wrapper around your `UL` so that you can move the background-color there. Then you position it inside its wrapper.

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="topnav">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

**additional CSS**

```
div.nav-wrapper {
    background-color: #333;
}
div.nav-wrapper ul.topnav {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

---

If you're able (depending on the browsers you need to support) to use `display:flex`, there's an even way more simple option. You just need to add some **CSS**:

```
ul.topnav {
    /* ... */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gqm7zdf9/1/

*I think you'll be able to continue with your media-queries from there...*

Comment: The first solution didn't work for some reason but I used the second one and it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @Dino: You're free to mark the answer as accepted. Thank you. --- If you need more guidance or help, just let me know.  ***`:)`***